# How do I reduce the space between Radio Buttons and shift them more towards left in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have implemented Radio button in Flutter namely **'Today'** , **'Tomorrow'** , **'User Input Date'**, and have wrapped them in a Column, but I am unable to reduce the space between the 3 radio buttons and also I am not able to move them towards the left. Is there any way I can shift them towards left side and decrease the default space taken between the radio button. Also I want to stick to the use of RadioListTile only.
I am attaching a picture to give a clear idea.
[image: Radio Button Flutter]

Code

```
 Column( 
                children: [
                  RadioListTile<DateTime>(
                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                    title: Text(
                      "Today",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
                    ),
                    value: today,
                    groupValue: selectedMatchDateFilter,
                    onChanged: (DateTime? value) => setState(() {
                      selectedMatchDateFilter = value;
                    }),
                  ),
                  RadioListTile<DateTime>(
                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                    title: Text(
                      "Tomorrow",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
                    ),
                    value: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day + 1),
                    groupValue: selectedMatchDateFilter,
                    onChanged: (DateTime? value) => setState(() {
                      selectedMatchDateFilter = value;
                    }),
                  ),
                  RadioListTile<DateTime>(
                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                    title: Row(
                      children: [
                        DropdownButton2<String>(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          buttonHeight: 30.h,
                          buttonWidth: 220.w,
                          items: const [
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "",
                              child: Text("Till Date"),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "",
                              child: Text("Precise Date"),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        1 == 2
                            ? Checkbox(
                                value: true,
                                onChanged: (bool? _value) {},
                              )
                            : IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                                onPressed: () => showDatePicker(
                                  context: context,
                                  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                  firstDate: DateTime(2022, 11, 16),
                                  lastDate: DateTime(2023, 1, 1),
                                ),
                              ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    value: DateTime.now(),
                    groupValue: selectedMatchDateFilter,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `visualDensity` and `dense` and `contentPadding` like this:

```
RadioListTile<DateTime>(
    activeColor: Colors.white,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: -4),//<-- add this
    dense: true,//<-- add this
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,//<-- add this
    
    title: Text(
      "Tomorrow",
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
    ),
    value: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
        DateTime.now().day + 1),
    groupValue: selectedMatchDateFilter,
    onChanged: (DateTime? value) => setState(() {}),
  ),
```

you can't get better than this, if its not good for you, you need make a custom tile like this:

```
Widget CustomRadioTile<T>(
      {required Function(T?) onChanged,
      required String title,
      required T groupValue,
      required T value,
      required BuildContext context}) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
         onChanged(value);
      },
      child: Row(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
            child: Radio<T>(
              value: value,
              groupValue: groupValue,
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

and use it like this:

```
CustomRadioTile<DateTime>(
          onChanged: (DateTime? value) => setState(() {
                selectedMatchDateFilter = value;
              }),
          title: 'Tomorrow',
          groupValue: selectedMatchDateFilter,
          value: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
              DateTime.now().day + 1),
          context: context),
```

Comment: Adding contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any options to change the width between the `Radio` and `Text` itself.
Instead you can create a separate widget which combines `Radio` and `Text` widgets.

```
class LabeledRadio extends StatelessWidget {
  const LabeledRadio({
    super.key,
    required this.label,
    required this.padding,
    required this.groupValue,
    required this.value,
    required this.onChanged,
  });

  final String label;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final bool groupValue;
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        if (value != groupValue) {
          onChanged(value);
        }
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: padding,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Radio<bool>(
              groupValue: groupValue,
              value: value,
              onChanged: (bool? newValue) {
                onChanged(newValue!);
              },
            ),
            Text(label),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Use this widget as a radio box then replace `RadioListTile` with this.